# Can I use dashes in Named Captures with .NET's System.Text.RegularExpressions?

Tags: .net, regex

Is it possible to do something like (?'A-B'\s*) ?

Comment: That depends on what you think that expression should match. Give us some examples and we can try and work out what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> (?<name1-name2>subexpression)
>
> (Balancing group definition.) Deletes
>   the definition of the previously
>   defined group name2 and stores in
>   group name1 the interval between the
>   previously defined name2 group and the
>   current group. If no group name2 is
>   defined, the match backtracks. Because
>   deleting the last definition of name2
>   reveals the previous definition of
>   name2, this construct allows the stack
>   of captures for group name2 to be used
>   as a counter for keeping track of
>   nested constructs such as parentheses.
>   In this construct, name1 is optional.
>   You can use single quotes instead of
>   angle brackets; for example,
>   (?'name1-name2').

Your example only works if there exists a group named B already defined in the regex, and you intend to do what A-B implies.

If you're asking if a group name can have a dash in it, no.  The dash has a special meaning in named groups.

For more information, see [the example in this topic.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx)